# Cannot find the certificate in either the LocalMachine store or the CurrentUser store - Remote Certificate Name Mismatch

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to consume a Mocked WebService created in SoapUI in my C# App but I get this error in the tracing :

> System.Net Information: 0 : [6756] SecureChannel#40583687 - Cannot find the certificate in either the LocalMachine store or the CurrentUser store.

I followed this procedure to create the certificate : 
[SoapUI Mock Services](http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/securing-mockservices-with-ssl.html)

This works fine on SoapUI but when I'm trying to access it via IE11 (`https://localhost:8443/test?WSDL`), it says there is a problem with the certificate. I continue, install it in the personal folder (& in the Trusted Root Cert Auth to be sure).
This is weird because even if I just installed the certificate with IE11, when I'm trying to relaod the WS in a new page, it shows me the same security error page ...
The certificate is present when I check in the MMC (Certificate -> current user).
I use the Thumbprint to identify the certificate in my C# app and it is recognized. I'm sure of it because I tried to set a bad Thumbprint and I get this error :

> Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria : ....

So now i'm getting this in my log file :

> System.Net Information: 0 : [6756] SecureChannel#40583687 - Cannot find the certificate in either the LocalMachine store or the CurrentUser store.
>   ...
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [6756] SecureChannel#40583687 - Remote certificate has errors:
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [6756] SecureChannel#40583687 -     Certificate name mismatch.
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [6756] SecureChannel#40583687 - Remote certificate was verified as invalid by the user.
>   System.Net Error: 0 : [6756] Exception in HttpWebRequest#12123890:: - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel..
>   System.Net Error: 0 : [6756] Exception in HttpWebRequest#12123890::GetResponse - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel..

I'm really stuck with this ... Any idea ?

EDIT : I tried the Visual Studio's Web Browser and i get this :
[image]

Comment: Is the certificate also present in the Machine Store?

Comment: Yes it is but I set this property in my app.config file :
`storeLocation="CurrentUser"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

I attached a Private Key to ce certificate and I reconfigured SoapUI via this http://www.discernment-solutions.com/?p=80
I installed the certificate into the Trusted Root Cert Auth to be sure it's recognized & tried the address in IE which proposed me to use the related certificate.

I've tested my WebService thanks to this method.